# String operation in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have a scenario in nodeJS.

I have an array of object like below which contains 2 attributes.

```
result.items = [
                    {
                        "organizationCode": "FP1",
                        "organizationName": "FTE Process Org"
                    },
                    {
                        "organizationCode": "T11",
                        "organizationName": "FTE Discrete Org"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "organizationCode": "M1",
                        "organizationName": "Seattle Manufacturing"
                    }
                ];
```

The scenario is like this. I have to filter result based on criteria.
  I have print output if either `organizationCode` or `organizationName` `starts with` particular character or `ends with` or it `contains` particular word.
for eg if user enters `starts with M` or `starts with "M"` below should return

```
            {
                "organizationCode": "M1",
                "organizationName": "Seattle Manufacturing"
            }
```

if user enters ends with org then

```
            {
                "organizationCode": "FP1",
                "organizationName": "FTE Process Org"
            },
            {
                "organizationCode": "T11",
                "organizationName": "FTE Discrete Org"
            },
```

and if it enters `contains 11` then below should return.

```
        {
            "organizationCode": "T11",
            "organizationName": "FTE Discrete Org"
        },
```

I have thousands of record. I am looking for optimize way to get output. I am new to `NodeJs` so struggling to complete it.

Comment: The user has to write a sentence? Not just have a input field for the search term and a select field for the filter operation?

Comment: only input field and search item. We will receive these 2 items from another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const result = {};
result.items = [{
    "organizationCode": "FP1",
    "organizationName": "FTE Process Org"
  },
  {
    "organizationCode": "T11",
    "organizationName": "FTE Discrete Org"
  },
  {
    "organizationCode": "M1",
    "organizationName": "Seattle Manufacturing"
  }
];

let inputText = "starts with M"; // example input text

const lastSpaceIndex = inputText.lastIndexOf(' ');

const secondPartOfInput = inputText.substring(lastSpaceIndex + 1).trim();

const firstPartOfInput = inputText.substring(0, lastSpaceIndex).trim().toLowerCase();

const filtered = result.items.filter(item => {
  if (firstPartOfInput === "starts with")
    return item.organizationCode.startsWith(secondPartOfInput) || item.organizationName.startsWith(secondPartOfInput);
  if (firstPartOfInput === "ends with")
    return item.organizationCode.endsWith(secondPartOfInput) || item.organizationName.endsWith(secondPartOfInput);
  if (firstPartOfInput === "contains")
    return item.organizationCode.includes(secondPartOfInput) || item.organizationName.includes(secondPartOfInput);
  return false;
})
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Awesome...thank you @Christian. I really dont know how many thanks I should send you. you made my task much easier Christian. I was highly frustrated.

Comment: Hello @Christian little change in user input and I am getting error. It is actually object not array. I tried to modify the code but still error. I have asked another question only input is changed.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924759/string-operation-in-nodejs-objects

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you edit your question so that it reflects your comment?

Answer (score 1):

Providing that you're filtering on the values of the items only and that the criteria is that the value `startsWith` the search term, doing this:

```js
result.items = [
    {
        "organizationCode": "FP1",
        "organizationName": "FTE Process Org"
    },
    {
        "organizationCode": "T11",
        "organizationName": "FTE Discrete Org"
    }, 
    {
        "organizationCode": "M1",
        "organizationName": "Seattle Manufacturing"
    }
];

let result = data.filter(item => {
    let match = false;
    Object.keys(item).forEach((k) => {
        if (item[k].startsWith(input)) {  // What is the search criteria?
            match = true;
        }
    });
    return match;
});
```

Should give you the result you want, but first, however, you have to figure out how you want to know what the user is asking for (`startsWith`, `endsWith` or `contains`)